# How do I create a listener(I think thats what its called) to trigger an event when the conditions are meet?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, event-handling

I need to trigger an even when a condition is met(ie. a randomly moving object reaches a certain spot), however I need it to be listening all the time, kind of like buttons, which are listening all the time for when you press it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`NotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and add an observer to it:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:yourObserver selector:yourSelector name:kNotificationName object:nil];
```

this will make `yourObserver` get notifications sent like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationName object:self userInfo:nil];
```

you can read the reference for more options about sending an `userInfo` object with the notification.

EDIT:

as to when posting the notification, you are not providing much context, but in general the only way to know if an object has reached a given position is to check each time that the object is moved on screen.

you might think about using one of the physics engines that are used for games (chipmunk, box2d) to check for collisions with fixed spots... but whether this option makes sense for you depends on your app...

if you are moving the object responding to touch events, then the proper place where to check if the object has reached the specified position is `touchesMoved`.

Comment: But how will I know when to post the notification? Is there a way to post the notification when an object reaches a certain position on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You might be talking about notifications? They are represented by an `NSNotification` and are queued and dispatched by `NSNotificationCenter`.

The notification center is a shared singleton of the system, so to use it, you ask for it's `+defaultCenter` like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter *myCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
```

You can register yourself as an *observer* of a given notification in one of two primary ways. First, the traditional one:

```
  [myCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name: NSApplicationWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

This tells the notification center to send the selector `handleNotification:` to `self` whenever an `NSApplicationWillHideNotification` is posted to the queue. The argument to `handleNotification:` will be the `NSNotification` object posted to the queue.

The "name" determines the "type" or "kind" of notification you want to be notified about. I don't think there's any big canonical list of these anywhere, but most are discoverable via documentation. Looking at the "NSApplication Class Reference", for instance, has a whole section at the bottom called "Notifications" that explains which ones it posts and why.

Note the last argument to `-addObserver:selector:name:object:`. If you pass an object there instead of `nil`, then you will only receive notifications sent from that object (as opposed to all notifications with that name posted anywhere on the system... which could be very noisy.)

Note that for every notification you register for, you should also unregister for. Bad things can happen if your observer gets deallocated and the notification center tries to message junk memory! In your `-dealloc` (or equivalent) make sure you add:

```
[myCenter removeObserver:self name:NSApplicationWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

The second way to register for a notification is with a block:

```
[self setMyNotificationObserver:[myCenter addObserverForName:NSApplicationWillHideNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
    // Do something...
}]];
```

`name:` and `object:` are the same. But instead of registering an object with a selector, you're registering a block that will get called whenever a notification with the given name is received. The additional parameter "queue" allows you to specify which `NSOperationQueue` the notification is executed on. This is one of the key advantages to using this style of notification handling. Normally a notification's observer is called on whatever thread posted the original notification. This lets you specify that the handler is always called on the given thread. Very useful for UI updates which *must* be performed on the main thread.

Finally, note that we assign the value returned by `-addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` to a property `myNotificationObserver`. This is how we unregister our observers when using block syntax. We use it like so:

```
[myCenter removeObserver:[self myNotificationObserver]];
```

You can also, of course, post your own custom notifications to `NSNotificationCenter`. Read up on this and all sorts of other notification stuff in the [Notification Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is called Key Value Observing ([KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)).
If randomlyMovingObject has a synthesized property, that contains the spot, you could start observing it using the following line:

```
[randomlyMovingObject addObserver:theObserver forKeyPath:@"spot" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
```

In order to react to changes concerning spot you have to implement the following method in the observer:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)theKeyPath ofObject:(id)theObject change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([theKeyPath isEqualToString:@"spot"]) {
        // react to changes
    }
}
```

Each time the property gets set, the observer gets notified.